# Interrupt in java thread

Tags: java, interrupt

I have a vector storing String objects. I want to put a check on vector which must ensure that if new element is added an interrupt is called. How can i write interrupt service routine (If possible) in JAVA?

Comment: Can you show what you've got so far?

Comment: where do those elements come from?

Comment: Daniel! So far i have run an other thread which checks if the size of the vector has changed and if so i run desired code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a simple solution is to make a wrapper for your vector :

```
class MyVector {
  private Vector;

  public setVector(Vector v){
    this.vector = v;
  }

  public add(String s){
    intruptService();
    vector.add(s);
  }

  private intruptService(){
     //TODO
     your-code
  }

}
```

other more complicated solution is using [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern.).

Comment: that's why i asked about the origin of vector elements above. your wrapper assumes that the addition of a new element, is a synchronous event

Comment: what is other cases than `add` ?

Comment: an element may come asynchronously, at arbitrary time instance, for example from some serial connection. that's actually the very purpose of ISR, to handle async events. here we don't know the complete story though

Comment: I have defined vectors in parent class which are shared by many child classes. One child class is adding objects in vector. Others just store data from vectors to database in SQL.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am getting data from USB serial port on the computer and data goes to vector so as you mentioned it looks like an asynchronous event.

Comment: @user3544854 you can replace the wrapper with with the vector.